# Add symbols of LKM to kernel

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

I am trying to get my android kernel working but I have a kernel module that is needed in order to get access to the file system of the device. Unfortunately there is no source code available so there are only the pre-compiled module and the kernel source. The kernel now tries to load the module without success. In the Module.symvers file in the kernel root directory the symbol that is needed is missing but the manufacturer of the device delivered a Module.symvers file from the root of the kernel source tree which includes all symbols that are needed.

How can I include those symbols in my kernel to get the module working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the config file of the kernel. It disabled some features so the module would not load.